# With Javascript and regex remove wrapping <p tags from around <img tags

Tags: javascript, regex

**Remove wrapping *<p* tags from around *<img* tags with Javascript**

Any ideas how to do this with Javascript and not php etc.
The only example I can find online is with PHP

```
preg_replace('​/<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1\2\3', $content);
```

Any help / guidance to refactor this into Javascript?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why use a reg exp? Is this not in the DOM?

Comment: It is coming from a headless CMS backend to nextjs/react frontend - wanted to strip the unnecessary garbage before outputting to the DOM.

Comment: If this is client side code, then you can use DOM manipulation to achieve what you want

Comment: @Martin can't you output to the DOM but hidden, fix the things you need to fix, then unhide it?

Comment: the html content (a long string) is coming from an API  - I was wanting to remove any unnecessary tags before outputting to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the `<p>` tag that only has `<img>` tag as its child, you may try this regex:

- Regex

```regex
<p\b[^<>\/]*>\s*(<img\b[^<>]*>)\s*<\/p>
```

- Substitution

```
$1
```

---

```
<p\b[^<>\/]*>           // opening <p> tag
\s*                     // optional white spaces
(<img\b[^<>]*>)         // <img> tag, and capture it in group 1
\s*                     // optional white spaces
<\/p>                   // closing </p> tag
```

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wCRg6K/1/)

```js
const text = '<p class="text">test</p><p class="image"> <img src="vvv" /> </p>';

const regex = /<p\b[^<>\/]*>\s*(<img\b[^<>]*>)\s*<\/p>/g;

const result = text.replace(regex, '$1');

console.log(text);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: helped a lot, thanks